# Prefix all columns in T-SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given a table "ABC" with columns Col1, Col2 and Col3 it is possible to automatically generate something like the following:

```
SELECT
Col1 AS 'ABC_Col1', 
Col2 AS 'ABC_Col2',
Col3 AS 'ABC_Col3' 
FROM ABC
```

I have a table without a fixed set of columns (users are able to append their own columns) where I still need the column prefix (because it is needed in a JOIN/CTE with other tables that also have columns with the names Col1, Col2 etc...)

Therefore I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
SELECT
T0.* AS 'ABC_T.*', 
FROM ABC T0
```

Which is of course not valid SQL, but can it be done somehow so the "*" columns all get the same prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a map of old column names and new column names:

```
SELECT syscolumns.name as old_column_name, 'ABC_' + syscolumns.name as new_column_name
   FROM sysobjects 
        JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
   WHERE sysobjects.name = 'ABC'
ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid
```

From there it's just some dynamic sql. I'm still playing with it.

**EDIT**

OK, I ditched that.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT '

DECLARE @old_column_name varchar(50)
DECLARE @getNext CURSOR
SET @getNext = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT syscolumns.name
       FROM sysobjects 
            JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
       WHERE sysobjects.name = 'ABC'
OPEN @getNext
FETCH NEXT FROM @getNext INTO @old_column_name
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

    --BUILD DYNAMIC SQL
    SET @sql = @sql + @old_column_name + ' AS ''ABC_' + @old_column_name + ''', '

FETCH NEXT FROM @getNext INTO @old_column_name
END
CLOSE @getNext
DEALLOCATE @getNext

--REMOVE FINAL COMMA AND ADD TABLE
SET @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, LEN(@sql)) + ' FROM ABC'

exec(@sql)
```

A) this is terrible performance (because it's a cursor)

B) I know you're not meant to do work for people on here, but I got carried away.

C) I considered not even posting this because of how poor of an answer I feel it is, but it's a least an idea.

Comment: Thank you for the effort.. I was hoping there was another way than dynamic sql (and since there seem not to be I'm not going to go on this route)...

Answer (score 2):

You seem confused as to what column aliases do.  As you can see in your `select` clause, you're already only selecting fields from `T0` by referencing `T0.*`.  You can still reference those fields as `T0.<whatever>` later in your query without aliasing the fields, you will just have to refer to them by their full field name, ie, `T0.[My Users Suck And Make Really Long Field Names]`.

EDIT: To be more clear, you can not change the prefix of a field by aliasing it.  You can only change the name of it.  The prefix of the field is the alias of the table that it comes from.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?  Nothing I said here is incorrect.

Comment: @Donnie: Likely someone's tactical downvoting

Comment: I know T0.* can be referenced as To.<Whatever> but as I mention this sample is later to be used in a more advance join and a  Common Table Expression (CTE). And at that time there will be a T0, T1, T2, etc where some of the fields have the same column names.. in joins * will still work but in CTE's it is not possible to have the same column-names twice...

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you'll be able to do this is by creating some dynamic SQL.